# Aggregate Query Returns Results in Dev Console but not Apex

Tags: apex, soql, aggregate

I have an `Apex Class` that retrieves an aggregate result of `Contacts` per `Accounts` in order to validate a maximum of 2 `Contacts` of a certain type.

I have tried several things. First I used a set and passed in all `Account` ids, but I got no results. Then I built the query in a string and also got no results. But if I run the query in the developer console query editor I do get the results I expect. Why does my query not work in `Apex`?

**Apex:**

```
public static map<id,String> beforeInsertHandler (Contact[] consList) {
    //create a map of errors per contact and return at and of method if any entry added
    map<id,String> exceptionsMap = new map<id,String>();

    //get map of all principals per account being inserted
    map<id,Contact> ContactsMap = new map<id,Contact>();
    set <String> accIds = new set<String>();
    for(Contact con:consList){
        if(con.loan__Contact_Type__c == 'Principal' && con.Active__c==true){
            ContactsMap.put(con.AccountId,con);
            system.debug('### adding contact accIds: ' + accIds);
            accIds.add(con.AccountId);
        }
    }

    String query = 'Select count(id) cnt, AccountId  From Contact where AccountId IN (\'';
    for(String accid: accIds){
        query+= accId + '\',';
    }
    String aggQuery = query.left(query.length()-1);  

    aggQuery += ') AND Active__c=true AND loan__contact_Type__c= \'Principal\' group by AccountId';

    AggregateResult[] ars= database.query(aggQuery);
    //THE QUERY ABOVE RETURNS 0 RECORDS WHEN I HAVE INSTERTED SEVERAL CONTACTS THAT MEET THE CRITERIA

    //get aggregate count of principals per account and validate if active principals count is greater than 2        
    for(AggregateResult ar:ars) {
        system.debug('### aggregate contacts:' + ar);
        integer principalCnt = (integer)ar.get('cnt');
        string accId = (string)ar.get('AccountId');

        if(principalCnt >=2 && ContactsMap.containsKey(accId)) {
            for(Contact con: consList) {
                if(accId == con.AccountId) {
                    exceptionsMap.put(con.id,'The Account for this Contact already contains the maximum allowed of 2 active Principals.');
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not even have a `return` statement and hence won't compile.

Comment: Also please post your working `SOQL` verbatim.

Comment: Also, are you sure the code that calls this method is passing in a collection that contains elements to begin with and you're not passing in an empty `List<Contact>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the method name, it seems the method is being **called from a before insert event on contact object**.

if that's the case, the query will not get the contacts you are currently inserting. (since you are running it before the records are inserted)

if you **change that to after insert** its should work.

Comment: The issue was in fact the before insert event as Vamsi Krishna stated. once I updated that the code worked perfect. I am sorry if the code was a bit vague as it did have a return statement ONLY if exceptionsMap was not empty, but I may have accidentally removed that when removing sensitive data, also the list being passed was always populated as it was coming from a trigger.new on an insert trigger. the final version went back to just using the query in a for loop for the aggregateresult object instead of building the query string and passing it to database.query as per this code.